# What does % mean in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development

Im learning solidity through cryptozombies.io and the first lesson ive come across this 83 % 7 + 1 = 7, does this mean that the floor division of 83 by 7 + 1 is equal to 7?

Answer (score 2):

`%` is the [modulo operator](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#modulo), it gives the remainder after integer division.

In your case, `83 % 7 = 6 + 1 = 7`

You can find more details about modulo and other operators inside the [official Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html).